# Permissions to start, update AWS IOT job

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I have onMessage function in my AWSIotTopic class which starts AWS job when AWS IoT job created (listens topic $aws/things/%s/jobs/notify-next). I can't change the job status from my local java application. When I attach a policy to my registered certificate with all permissions, i.e.:

```
"Action": "*",
"Resource": "*"
```

my applications work and I can change job status. Which permissions I have to add to change job status?

```
"Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "iot:UpdateJobExecution",
    "iot:StartNextPendingJobExecution"
    ],
  "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:eu-west-2:125960935295:thing/thingID"
}
```

above permissions didn't allow to start and update job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved. It is necessary to add `iot:Receive` besides `iot:Subscribe` to the topic notify-next. All permissions to perform the job on device:

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<region>:<awsID>:topicfilter/$aws/things/<deviceID>/jobs/notify-next"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<region>:<awsID>:topic/$aws/things/<deviceID>/jobs/notify-next"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<region>:<awsID>:topic/some"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<region>:<awsID>:client/<deviceID>"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:UpdateJobExecution",
        "iot:StartNextPendingJobExecution"
        ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:<region>:<awsID>:thing/<deviceID>"
    }
  ]
}
```